# A single message to provide report of all Cron jobs

Tags: cron

We are using a Cron server in Amazon AWS,  i.e., a EC2 c1.medium ubuntu server instance. Daily 16 cronjobs(14 as root user & 2 as ubuntu user) run in that instance @ different timings. Mails on the cron job status are sent after execution of the job. Therefore the complete day i will be receiving the mails for every cronjob executed i.e, 16 mails. Is there a way that at the end of the day i get an email stating the number of cronjobs executed successfully and the ones that failed. Can we configure something like that on Ubuntu 10.04 server.

Answer (score 0):

The email will not be sent if there was nothing on stdout. If you redirect all of your output, no mails will be sent.

```
00 4 * * * /usr/bin/domything >> /var/log/domything.log
```

You can mail out all of your logs with yet another cron job:

```
00 1 * * * mv /var/log/domything.log /tmp/ && cat /tmp/domything.log
```

(just be aware that any jobs that run during that time would still be writing at the old log)

You can also redirect your mail to another address:

```
MAILTO=mycron@example.com
00 4 * * * /usr/bin/domything
```

and then set up a .forward there that pipes all incoming things into a file and when it grows past 10kb mail them to another address...

Possibilities, possibilities!

Then again, wrong site. This should be on ServerFault.

Comment: Thanx for you reply Amadan, What you mean to say is maintain a separate log file to append the results of all the cronjobs and send it at the end of the day.